# Flow Type: Get object property names based on flow-types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Supposedly I have the following type:

```
declare interface SomeClass {
    x?: ?number;
    y?: ?string;
}
```

Now I apply this type to an object SomeObject, which will be fetched from a backend call. The problem is, sometimes the returned value would be something like this:

```
{ "x": 1, "y": "Some String", "z": "Additional Payload" }
```

The question is: how can I **remove** these so called additional payload using Flow? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Why do you use `?` in the `x` and `y` keys? If `z` key sometimes may appear or not, use `?` sign with it.

Comment: well, it is required to remove the key `z`. And sometimes there are more additional keys like `z1`, `z2`, etc. What I want is a clean object containing only `x` and `y`. Can this be done using Flow or should I try something else?

Comment: I think you will have to just pick the desired keys from the object. Flow doesn't have such features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow is a type-level language which statically describes JavaScript code. It has no runtime effect and does not change the meaning of your code — if you remove the Flow annotations from a (correctly typed) program then it will run exactly the same. This is one of Flow's design goals, which distinguishes it from languages like TypeScript.

With that in mind, it is clear that Flow cannot help you with changing the structure of an object. However, if you assign an object a type which has only certain fields, Flow can help make sure that you don't use fields that you weren't supposed to:

```
type MyType = {
    x?: ?number,
    y?: ?string
}
let foo: MyType = { "x": 1, "y": "Some String", "z": "Additional Payload" };

foo.z; // ERROR! Even though z is there, it's not part of MyType
```

But let's say you want it to be stricter earlier, and just not allow any additional properties in the assignment. You can use `{| .. |}` to indicate that no other fields are allowed:

```
type MyType = {|
    x?: ?number,
    y?: ?string
|}
let foo: MyType = { "x": 1, "y": "Some String", "z": "Additional" }; // ERROR!
```

Note that you will still need to check the structure of data if it is from an external source. Flow can only use compile-time information.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't remove that additional payload with flow. As flow is only a static type checker and all flow statements will be removed for you runnable JavaScript file. But you could use something like that to remove the rest of the payload:

```
const { x, y } = object;
object = { x, y };
```